# Does TDengine support writing a comment for each field?

Tags: tdengine

Does TDengine support writing a comment for each field?
How to write statements that support SQL?
Can TDengine only store change data, that is, if the collected data is the same as the previous time value already stored in the database, it will not be written?

Answer (score 0):

Only table creation support comment.

In TDengine 2.x, update capability is controlled by the parameter of db creation. 0 means not able to update. 1 means only update whole row. 2 means able to update specific column of a row.

In TDengine 3.0, update is supported by default.